# What happens if Keras Tensorflow's `Model.fit`'s target/output is `None`?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I was looking at this code: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/variational_autoencoder.py#L198, where `Model.fit()` is called without an output or target Tensor. At first, I thought the behavior of `Model.fit()` is to use the input as the output (which would make sense for this autoencoder implementation). But then I looked into the documentation, and that's not what it says: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit

It implies when `y`, the target, is `None`, `x` should be some kind of structure that contains both the input and target.

But it's clear in this autoencoder implementation, that's not what happens (`x` only contains the input). Could someone explain what happens in this case?

Comment: I just asked a similar question few hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57678886/keras-fit-with-y-none-with-embedding-layer/57679049#57679049

Comment: @hadron Interesting question. Thanks. Though in my case, a custom loss is defined. If I may ask, what prompted you to try omitting the target?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Keras documentation for [model.fit](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit) the following is stated:

> - y: Numpy array of target (label) data (if the model has a single output), or list of Numpy arrays (if the model has multiple outputs).
>     If output layers in the model are named, you can also pass a
>     dictionary mapping output names to Numpy arrays.  **y can be None
>     (default) if feeding from framework-native tensors (e.g. TensorFlow
>     data tensors).**

Now, notice that in the variational autoencoder example, the argument `outputs` of the model [`vae`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/variational_autoencoder.py#L161) is a TensorFlow native tensor, since it is given by the output of another model [`decoder`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/variational_autoencoder.py#L155) (a TensorFlow native tensor) whose `inputs` argument is *independent* of the `vae`'s input.

Comment: rvinas, thanks for explaining, but I don't think I'm grasping the main points. First, what is a native tensor and what is its purpose? I could not immediately find documentation on this. When I first read the documentation you cited above, I thought the native tensors it's referring to is a specialized data structure containing both inputs and targets. No?

Comment: You say the decoder's `inputs` argument is independent of the `vae`'s input. Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but the decoder's input is linked to the encoder's output (line 20), and the encoder's output is linked to the vae's input. So in this way, the decoder's `inputs` is not independent of `vae`'s input. In fact, we could avoid defining the encoder and decoder sub`Models` in that code, and just define one vae `Model`; would that change anything?

Comment: What is a native tensor? It is not a specialized data structure containing both inputs and targets. It is a tensor from a specific Keras backend, in this case a TF tensor.

Comment: Regarding your second comment, you are completely right - the `decoder` input is linked to the encoder's output. What I am trying to say is that the `decoder` model is defined independently of `vae`. And again, nice point about defining a single model `vae` - in this case the output tensor would not be treated as an independent TF tensor, but rather as a tensor that depends directly on the model's input. In this case, you would have to provide the argument `y` to `fit`. As far as I know, using the "sub `Model`s" breaks these dependencies.

Comment: Thanks again rvinas; so what I understand thus far is: by decoupling into sub`Model`s, the output of our `Model` becomes a native TF tensor, which makes it optional to specify in `fit`. But why have this native tensor requirement? It seems kind of superficial - we should have the ability to *not* specify the target `y` even if it's not native, shouldn't we? I mean, the single model `vae` we were talking about would otherwise be unnecessarily affected by this requirement.

Comment: @flow2k Apologies for the delay. What I understand is that the dependencies are broken when decoupling into sub`Model`s (the tensors are always TF-native) and that this is why Keras does not complain about `y` being `None`. About your second question, if you don't provide `y` and there isn't any TF tensor to obtain `y` from, where would you get the labels from? In this specific VAE example, one could internally set `y=x` when `y` is not provided, but what if the output shape is not the same? Even though it might work for the `vae`, the behavior in other cases would not be clear.

Comment: rvinas, okay. I guess since TF is still fairly young and in rapid development, this level of detail might change from one implementation to the next.